# mongodb how to query referenced property and return primary collection with referenced property joined

Tags: mongodb, join, reference

Cat Collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8d0d16e4fec1ad4779249"),
    "description" : ObjectId("5ea9af047d6a4f6480fd42f4")
}
```

Description Collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea9af047d6a4f6480fd42f4"),
    "color" : "ginger"
}
```

I'd like to obtain all in Cat collection where the `Cat.description.color` property equals `ginger` and the `Cat.description` property is joined;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8d0d16e4fec1ad4779249"),
    "description" : {
                      "_id" : ObjectId("5ea9af047d6a4f6480fd42f4"),
                      "color" : "ginger"
                    }
}
```

I have the following aggregate query which works, but seems inefficient due to the second `$lookup`. Given the `$match` provides us with the necessary `Description` objects, is there a better way ?

```
db.Description.aggregate(
{
    $match:{
        $and:[
            { color: 'ginger' }
        ]
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'Cat',
        let: { descId: '$_id' },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $eq: ['$description', '$$descId']
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: 'cat'
    }
},
{
    $unwind: '$cat'
},
{
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: '$cat'
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'Description',
        localField: 'description',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'description'
    }
},
{
    $unwind: '$description'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for adding code snippets. Could you edit the title of your question so that it is actually formulated as a question? Maybe something that starts with `how to...`?

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate on Cat collection and get the expected result

```
db.cat.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "description",
      let: { catId: "$description" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$catId" ] },
                { $eq: [ "$color", "ginger" ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "description"
    }
  },
  
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xtp683A6uIb)**

Comment: thanks for the reply. Testing your answer, I found when adding a second entry to the Cat collection, the result was incorrect; [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v0SFm5CDoBI)

Comment: @010 because u said  `color = ginger`, if u dont need documents whose description is empty, simply u use a `$match` after the lookup https://mongoplayground.net/p/tnXQWTn0GxD

Comment: @010 does that help you?

Comment: when testing on a Cat collection with a few thousand entries, your query times out. The query I posted above completes in ~3 seconds.